# Hiding optional outputs in Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, contour, gui

I am creating a model in ArcGIS Desktop version 10.7.1 that uses the "Topo to Raster" tool to convert contours (line shapefile) to a raster. The contours are actually representing lines of equal aircraft noise (modeled from flight paths, altitude, distance from airport, etc) but the process should be equivalent to creating a DEM from elevation contours.

The "Topo to Raster" tool comes with a variety of optional outputs, which I do not care about, because I am only interested in the resulting raster. I cannot delete these optional outputs without deleting the whole tool (any attempt to click and delete them selectively removes the whole thing), but they makes my model appear cluttered and hard to read.

Since they are totally irrelevant to the rest of my process, which is already large and contains many tools, I would really like to delete these extraneous outputs, or at least hide them from the graphical interface's flowchart. To be clear, the tool itself works fine, without any of the optional outputs specified, this question is just about aesthetics. I like to use the Model Builder as a graphic to show and explain my methodology.

I checked to make sure this question wasn't addressed elsewhere first, and I have attached a sample image below.

[image: Topo to Raster tool in the Model Builder]

Comment: Just place them on top of each other.

Comment: This doesn't really work because any time I use the Auto Layout button to realign they'll become unstacked. However, I found a suitable workaround. I was able to lower "Minimum Spacing Between Elements" to 1 in the diagram properties, and lower the length and width of the unwanted elements to 1 in their display properties. Still doesn't look great, but it's far more compact. Thanks anyways.